# Is there a reason to my second instantiated object takes my first object's value?

Tags: c#, hashtable

When I insert a second Object(a Child), I need to assign to his parent the name of his child (having already the Child object, that has the parents name in a property), but when I call the Parent object always returns the child object.

I'm using a Hashtable to store "Cargo" objects.

```
// Hashtable(key,value)
TablaCargos(CargoObject.Name, CargoObject)
```

And every Cargo should have a Parent and a Child list

Part of my class Cargo

```
class Cargo {
  private string nombre;
  private string codigo;
  private string padre;
  private List<string> hijos = new List<string>();

  public Cargo() {
    nombre = "";
    codigo = "";
    padre = "";
    hijos = new List<string>();
  }

  //getter and setters
}
```

My form

```
Cargo cargo = new Cargo();
Cargo cargoHijo = new Cargo();
Cargo cargoPadre = new Cargo();
Hashtable TablaCargos = new Hashtable();
string Root = "";

private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  cargo.Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
  cargo.Codigo = txtCodigo.Text;
  cargo.Padre = txtPadre.Text;

  TablaCargos.Add(txtNombre.Text, cargo);

  Ordenamiento(txtNombre.Text);
}

private void Ordenamiento(string cargoActual) {

  cargoHijo = (Cargo)TablaCargos[cargoActual];

  if (cargoHijo.Padre == "") {
    // THIS IS A PARENT
    Root = cargoActual;
  } else {
    // THIS IS A CHILD
    AsignarPadre(cargoHijo.Padre, cargoHijo.Nombre);
}

private void AsignarPadre(String Padre, String Hijo)
{
  // THE PROBLEM IS HERE, CLEARLY I SEND THE Parent's KEY

  cargoPadre = (Cargo)TablaCargos[Padre];

  // BUT IN THE NEXT LINE cargoPadre TAKES THE VALUE OF THE CHILD
  // THE SAME VALUE OF cargoHijo

  cargoPadre.Hijos.Add(Hijo);
}
```

I expect to assign the child's name to the parent's child property, but the child takes it.

Maybe I miss an instantiation or, I don't know

Comment: How do you store values into TablaCargos?

Comment: You would have much more fun (fun level 100) with the more modern generic `Dictionary` than a `Hashtable`...

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't include key details like how the TableCargos gets populated, and how the Cargos' properties are being set. Can you try to get your problem narrowed down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Why are you setting `Hijos` to null in the constructor when you are initializing it in the declaration statement?
If you expect an answer then you must give a code sample that shows how the program is not behaving to your specifications.

Comment: Hey, sounds interesting, I was just seeing a bit about `Dictionary`. I'll consider that in the future, thanks. But here I need to use `Hashtable`, because it's a homework about that.

Comment: I've made some changes to the code, and now it's more complete. The line that is bothering me is this `cargoPadre = (Cargo)TablaCargos[Padre];`

Comment: @Jeff and how do you make distinction between parent and child objects, if they have the same name, and if I understood good, the key is the name, so they have the same key?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was solved with this line `cargo = new Cargo();` at the beginning `btnAdicionar_Click`.
Thank you all for your time and advice. :)

Comment: That line of code isn't in your question. Please fix your question or just delete everything if you can't.

Comment: Isn't in my question because I fixed it after posting this, then I write an answer because I solved it, I did wrong to answer my own question? So should I have just edited it?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. You should just make sure that the question has enough detail in it that the answer makes sense. Right now there is a disconnect between the question and the answer. It's unanswerable by anyone else and currently doesn't provide any value for future readers. Could you leave your answer and fix the question please?